# call a non inherited method of a derived class

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance

I have these 5 classes.. One base class called Figura that is an abstract class, and 4 concrete derived classes.

[image: Classes]

I have to create an array of Figuras of size 8 (two Cuadrado, two Rectangulo, two Triangulo and two Circulo), so I did this:

```
Figuras[] figuras = new Figuras[8];
figuras[0] = new Cuadrado(1);
figuras[1] = new Cuadrado(2);
figuras[2] = new Rectangulo(2, 1);
figuras[3] = new Rectangulo(6, 2);
figuras[4] = new Triangulo(1, 2, 2);
figuras[5] = new Triangulo(3, 3, 4);
figuras[6] = new Circulo(1);
figuras[7] = new Circulo(4);
```

Then I iterate through the array to calculate the area and perimeter of every figure. The problem comes when I try to call the method calcularDiametro() that belongs only to the figure Circulo. How can I do that?

I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
foreach (Figuras f in figuras)
    if (f is Circulo)
        f.calcularDiametro();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a recommendation - use English when naming variables, classes, methods, etc. The same goes for comments. Although it's understandable what you're doing here, it won't be well accepted in an international team.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Filkolev, I actually do it. This was just an exercise to practice casting between classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast it to a `Circulo` in order to call `Circulo`-specific methods:

```
foreach (Figuras f in figuras) 
{
    if (f is Circulo)
        (Circulo)f.calcularDiametro();
}
```

Note that this is a bit wasteful because it does type-checking twice (which is a costly operation).  One way to do this without that waste is to use `as`:

```
foreach (Figuras f in figuras) 
{
    Circulo circ = f as Circulo;
    if (circ != null)
    {
        circ.calcularDiametro();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `as` opertor and prevent additional cast and improve performance

```
foreach (Figuras f in figuras)
{
    var c = f as Circulo;
    if (c != null)
        c.calcularDiametro();
}
```

You can also use `OfType` to get objects of specific type from your `Enumerable`

```
foreach (var c in figuras.OfType<Circulo>())
{
    c.calcularDiametro();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are technically correct yet wrong. Your problem is you should not initiate those calculations from outside the classes in the first place. The classes themselves should perform the calculations as needed, either in the constructor or when an external component requests the value of perimetro or diametro. That is encapsulation.

Comment: Encapsulation is the hiding of the inner workings of the calculations. The classes are doing that just fine. It seems to me that the `calcularDiametro` method does not apply to the other shapes so the it is perfectly fine for only a particular subclass to have this method.

Comment: I believe Martin is quite right, the design breaks some principles.

Comment: Thank you Glenner. To elaborate: hiding the calculation code yet requiring the client to initiate the calculation is pointless from an OOP perspective. You are not interested in the calculation, you are interested in the perimetro and the diametro only (properties of the shapes). Anything that needs to be done to produce those values should be hidden. It is like going to the bakery and not ask for a bread but instead tell the man to put dough in a shape, put it in the oven, wait for a couple of hours, take it out, put it in a sack and hand it to you. Who is making the bread now?